# Cannot connect a property to storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am building a master detail iPad application. Trying to connect a property declared in my view controller's.h file.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *aboutGame;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *gameDescription;
```

The file owner has been set as I am able to connect the *aboutGame property to a label on my storyboard. Trying to set the Text field to an element just does not seem to work. Am I missing something here?

The following shows up when attempting to connect the textfield. (Note the same is going wrong when trying to link a UIImageView also)

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: The picture is of a UITextView, not a UITextField. Can you be mixing the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `UITextField` in definition and `UITextView` on Interface builder. So it is not showing you the option to connect.

Try like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *gameDescription;
```